# ASP MVC: how to save files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, windows-server-2008

In visual studio i have the following scenario:

One solution with two project:

- An Asp MVC project
- A Web Api project

In a controller in the Asp MVC Project i want save files (uploaded) in the file system

1. Where i must save the files? In a folder inside the asp mvc project?
2. Is possible to save the files inside a folder in the C:\ file system. How To?

In the web api project i need to send to client the images saved by the asp mvc project.

1. How can i access the images if are inside the folder in the asp mvc project and not in the c:\ file system?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to save images and u are not sure where u should save in. If the question is this,

1. You need to save files (images) to Database if there will be more than one server. Because, if you save images to a server, other(s) can't reach them.
2. If there is just one server, u can store them to File System. However, you need to store information about images in order to reach when you need. Thus, you need Database anyway. So, storing images to database is a good option.

I think [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/829291/Resizing-and-Storing-Image-Files-File-System-and-D) will also help you to store image files to file system and database.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
byte[] image = Convert.FromBase64String(pImage);
string assemblyFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
File.WriteAllBytes(assemblyFolder + @"\" + "fileName", image);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes it is possible to save the file inside the project as long as you have write permission on the folder.

2.
To save the file in location form controller you can do something like this; (in the html side input type need to be file)

```
[HttpPost]
        public void UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(serverPath, fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
        }
```

3. If you went to access the file from other application my suggestion will be save the file in a common folder (possibly common network file system). You may have access permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible 

**Step 1**

create any name of action method in your controller

**Step 2**

Write the below code

```
public ActionResult File(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            try
            {
                string path = @"C:\File_Upload\";
                if (file != null)
                {
                    file.SaveAs(path + file.FileName);
                    return View();
                }
                else
                {
                    return View();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }                     
        }
```

**File**:is your action method name which is you to save your file in your given path 

**HttpPostedFileBase**:

```
The HttpPostedFileBase class is an abstract class that contains the same members as the HttpPostedFile class. The HttpPostedFileBase class lets you create derived classes that are like the HttpPostedFile class, but that you can customize and that work outside the ASP.NET pipeline.
```

**Step 3**

Create view which is store input tag for input file

Write below code in view

[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQUz9.png)